# Create a Teams like dynamic layout android

Tags: android, android-layout, video, grid

I am developing a video chat Android application and I want to achieve something like the Teams application layout. I want the screen to be divided in equal parts as many as the participants are.

For example in a 4 Participant call I want the screen to be like 2x2 Grid
If another one joins the room i want to divide it in 3x2 Grid.
If another one joins the room i want 3x3 Grid and so on....

How can i achieve this programmatically? Is there any example that shows something like that?

Comment: Use GridLayout. Check the documentation for understanding the flexibility of excess space distribution. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout#excess-space-distribution

Comment: Well...that was the solution! Thank you very much

Comment: I wrote the answer so you can accept it as an answer for others to refer to as the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use GridLayout. Check the documentation for understanding the flexibility of excess space distribution. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout#excess-space-distribution